# Elasticsearch Spring boot integration test

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-boot, integration-testing

I am looking for the way to add embedded elasticsearch to my spring boot integration test.

I looked at elastic search integration test but it does not work together with spring boot as both should uses different test runner.

I have a class test as below unfortunately it does not work with error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context information for thread:
>   Thread[id=1, name=main, state=RUNNABLE, group=main]. Is this thread
>   running under a class
>   com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner runner context?
>   Add @RunWith(class
>   com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner.class) to your
>   test class. Make sure your code accesses random contexts within
>   @BeforeClass and @AfterClass boundary (for example, static test class
>   initializers are not permitted to access random contexts).

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = App.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest("server.port:0")
public class TestExample extends ElasticsearchIntegrationTest {

    TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate = new TestRestTemplate();

    @Value("${local.server.port}")
    int port;

    @Test
    public void testOne(){
        ResponseEntity<String> results = testRestTemplate.getForEntity(String.format("http://localhost:%d/client/1", port), String.class);



     System.out.print(results);
    }

}
```

Does anybody has some ideas how to make them run or what is alternatives ??

Comment: How about this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-data-elasticsearch/ ?

Comment: I have seen this already. First I don't use spring-data, secondly I need embedded version of ES.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can actually do what you need without any additional elasticsearch testing dependencies. The idea is basically to create an embedded node and then use the [`NodeClient`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html#node-client) to communicate with it.

For that, I created my own `EmbeddedElasticsearchServer` class which looks (more or less) like this:

```
public class EmbeddedElasticsearchServer implements InitializingBean {

    public EmbeddedElasticsearchServer() {

        ImmutableSettings.Builder elasticsearchSettings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
                .put("http.enabled", "false")
                .put("path.data", "target/elasticsearch-data");

        node = nodeBuilder()
                .local(true)
                .settings(elasticsearchSettings.build())
                .node();

        client = node.client();


    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
         // Initialization stuff:
         // - create required indices
         // - define mappings
         // - populate with test data
    }

    public Client getClient() {
         return client;
    }

}
```

Then, in spring configuration (let's call it `integration-test-context.xml`) I did this:

```
<bean id="embeddedElasticsearchServer" 
      class="com.example.EmbeddedElasticsearchServer" />

<bean id="elasticsearchClient"
      class="org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient" 
      factory-bean="embeddedElasticsearchServer" 
      factory-method="getClient" />
```

Then you can just autowire the client in your test like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/integration-test-context.xml")
public abstract class AbstractElasticsearchIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private Client elasticsearchClient;

    // Your rests go here...

}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I will try it and accept the answer afterwards. :)

Comment: This answer helped me out so much. I had spent an entire day trying to make a version of org.elasticsearch.test.InternalTestCluster that I could embedd in a JerseyTest. This made things much easier. One thing to note is make sure you close the node and client somewhere. They need to be cleaned up.

Comment: In case it helps anyone else this only worked for me when path.data was an absolute path (with ES 1.7.3).

Comment: According to [the ElasticSearch pull requests](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/15354), the NodeBuilder has been removed and the Node class should be used directly instead.

Comment: ElasticsearchCrudRepository bean cannot be created if you use node client in integration test.

Comment: If I had multiple such tests, would it not start the server for each test?

Comment: It complains that I need to configure path.home, where then an elasticsearch instance should be.