# How to write unit tests in spring boot for elasticsearch

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, elasticsearch, integration-testing

I have to write unit tests of spring boot application with elasticsearch.

I've read a lot of documentation, and I've discovered that an embedded elasticsearch can be used, a bit like using H2 for DBMS.

Unfortunately, applying what I read and looking at some examples found on the net, I came to the conclusion that an embedded elasticsearch cannot be used for my purpose, or I don't know how to make it work.

Has anyone ever used an embedded elasticsearch to make me understand how he used it?

Comment: Can you please tell use a bit more what didn't work for you? And what do you wan to test? Do you want to test ElasticSearch or your code?

Comment: Please include what you have tried and also why do you think you cannot use an embedded elastic search for your tests? Why wouldn't it be useable?

Comment: I tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30675654/elasticsearch-spring-boot-integration-test

Obviously, I want to test my code.